# How to trigger a payable function using call function while testing in Foundary

Tags: foundry

"My doubt is about testing a payable function using `call` Method while testing in **`Foundry`**"

" Blockchain network-> `Ethereum`"

I have a payable function as shown >

```
contract First{

function func1(
    string memory _name,
    string memory _phone_no              
    ) public payable {  
      // some work
    }    
 }
```

I want to test this payable function using call function in boundary.
Here is my code ->
contract testing{

```
First f;        

function setUp() public {
    f = new First();
    
    (bool callSuccess, bytes memory data) = payable(address(this)).call{
        value: 1000000
    }(
    abi.encodeWithSignature(
            "func1(string,string)",
            "ABC",
            "xxxxxxxxxx"                
        )

      require(callSuccess, "Call failed");
    );
```

I am getting this error as shown ->

```
2023-10-10T15:32:30.044610Z ERROR forge::runner: setUp failed reason="EvmError: Revert" contract=0x7fa9385be102ac3eac297483dd6233d62b3e1496
```

Please anyone solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the test contract itself, your function should be like this:

```
function setUp() public {
    // f = new First();

    (bool callSuccess, bytes memory data) = address(f).call{value: 1000000}(
        abi.encodeWithSignature("func1(string,string)", "ABC", "xxxxxxxxxx")
    );
    require(callSuccess, "Call failed");
}
```

Comment: Yes It works!!.

Thank you for response

Comment: Awesome, can you mark this as an answer? It helps the community.

Comment: @ZartajAfser amazing, but what if the function call returns address or something else? How can you get it from `data`?

Comment: You can do it by simply by `abi.decode`. If you need a code example, I can provide it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

```
 f.func1{value: 1000000 ether}(_name, _phone_no);
```